# Validation for empty input fields using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I again encountered a problem for jquery form validation(related to empty input fields), I have three input fields, one for the first name, last name and date of birth, when I click submit button it does not show a warning message for the date of birth. The success.php file contains only a message "Registration Successful !". Here is my HTML code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head id="html">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"> </script>
 <style >
  #first-name{
   width: 300px;
   margin-top: 10px;
   margin-left: 510px;
   padding-left: 10px;
   border: 1px solid grey;
   border-radius: 5px;
  }
  #last-name{
   width: 300px;
   margin-top: 5px;
   margin-left: 510px;
   padding-left: 10px;
   border: 1px solid grey;
   border-radius: 5px;
  }
  #date-of-birth{
   width: 300px;
   margin-top: 5px;
   margin-left: 510px;
   padding-left: 10px;
   border: 1px solid grey;
   border-radius: 5px; 
  }
  #sign-up-button{
   width: 200px;
   margin-top: 10px;
   margin-left: 560px;
   font-size: 18px;
   border-radius: 50px;
  }
  #first-name-warning-message{ 
   padding-left: 640px;
   font-size: 18px;
   font-weight: bold;
  }
  #last-name-warning-message{
   padding-left: 640px;
   font-size: 18px;
   font-weight: bold;
  }
  #dob-warning-message{
   padding-left: 640px;
   font-size: 18px;
   font-weight: bold;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body id="body">
 <form id="sign-up" action="success.php" method="post">
  <div id="row-one">
   <input type="text" id="first-name" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" maxlength="15">
  </div>
  <div id="span-container">
   <span id="first-name-warning-message" class="text-danger"> </span>
  </div>
  <div id="row-two">
   <input type="text" id="last-name" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" maxlength="15">
  </div>
  <div id="span-container">
   <span id="last-name-warning-message" class="text-danger"> </span>
  </div>
  <div id="row-three">
   <input class="date-picker" id="date-of-birth" name="user_dob" placeholder="Date Of Birth" readonly="true">
  </div>
  <div id="span-container">
   <span id="dob-warning-message" class="text-danger"> </span>
  </div>
  <div id="row-four">
   <button id="sign-up-button" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"> Sign Up </button>
  </div>
 </form>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#first-name-warning-message').hide();
   $('#last-name-warning-message').hide();
   $('#dob-warning-message').hide();

   var first_name_error=false;
   var last_name_error=false;
   var dob_error=false;

   $('#first-name').focusout(function(){
    validate_first_name();
   });

   $('#last-name').focusout(function(){
    validate_last_name();
   });

   $('#date-of-birth').focusout(function(){
    validate_date_of_birth();
   });

   function validate_first_name(){
    var first_name=$('#first-name').val();
    var first_name_regex=/^[a-zA-Z ]{3,15}$/;
    if(first_name.length==''){
     $('#first-name-warning-message').show();
     $('#first-name-warning-message').html("Please Enter Your First Name !");
     first_name_error=true;
    }
    else if(first_name.length<3){
     $('#first-name-warning-message').show();
     $('#first-name-warning-message').html("First Name Not Valid !");
     first_name_error=true;
    }
    else if(!first_name_regex.test(first_name)){
     $('#first-name-warning-message').show();
     $('#first-name-warning-message').html("First Name Must Not Contain Any Digits Or Symbols !");
     first_name_error=true;
    }
    else{
     $('#first-name-warning-message').hide();
    }
   }

   function validate_last_name(){
    var last_name=$('#last-name').val();
    var last_name_regex=/^[a-zA-Z ]{3,15}$/;

    if(last_name.length==''){
     $('#last-name-warning-message').show();
     $('#last-name-warning-message').html("Please Enter Your Last Name !");
     last_name_error=true;
    }
    else if(last_name.length<3){
     $('#last-name-warning-message').show();
     $('#last-name-warning-message').html("Last Name Not Valid !");
     last_name_error=true;
    }
    else if(!last_name_regex.test(last_name)){
     $('#last-name-warning-message').show();
     $('#last-name-warning-message').html("Last Name Must Not Contain Any Digits Or Symbols !");
     last_name_error=true;
    }
    else{
     $('#last-name-warning-message').hide();
    }
   }

   function validate_date_of_birth(){
       $("#date-of-birth").datepicker({
           dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',
           changeMonth: true,
           changeYear: true,
           onClose: function validate_date_of_birth(selectedDate){
               var date_of_birth=selectedDate;
               if(date_of_birth.length==''){
                  $('#dob-warning-message').html("Please Enter Your Date Of Birth !");
                   $('#dob-warning-message').show();
                   dob_error=true;
               }
               else{
                   $('#dob-warning-message').hide();
               }
              }
       }); 
      }

      $('#sign-up').submit(function(){
       first_name_error=false;
       last_name_error=false;
       dob_error=false;

       validate_first_name();
       validate_last_name();
       validate_date_of_birth();

       if((first_name_error==false)&&(last_name_error==false)&&(dob_error==false)){
        return true;
       }
       else{
        return false;
       }
      });
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please Help

Comment: `if(date_of_birth.length==''){` should be `if(date_of_birth.length===0){`

Comment: I've tried, still not working

Comment: Are you completely sure there is no valid names with 2 letters only? Some asian names like "Li", maybe?

Comment: `last_name.length==''` sould be `last_name.length===0'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($("#date-of-birth").datepicker("getDate") === null)
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head id="html">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"> </script>
     <style >
      #first-name{
       width: 300px;
       margin-top: 10px;
       margin-left: 510px;
       padding-left: 10px;
       border: 1px solid grey;
       border-radius: 5px;
      }
      #last-name{
       width: 300px;
       margin-top: 5px;
       margin-left: 510px;
       padding-left: 10px;
       border: 1px solid grey;
       border-radius: 5px;
      }
      #date-of-birth{
       width: 300px;
       margin-top: 5px;
       margin-left: 510px;
       padding-left: 10px;
       border: 1px solid grey;
       border-radius: 5px; 
      }
      #sign-up-button{
       width: 200px;
       margin-top: 10px;
       margin-left: 560px;
       font-size: 18px;
       border-radius: 50px;
      }
      #first-name-warning-message{ 
       padding-left: 640px;
       font-size: 18px;
       font-weight: bold;
      }
      #last-name-warning-message{
       padding-left: 640px;
       font-size: 18px;
       font-weight: bold;
      }
      #dob-warning-message{
       padding-left: 640px;
       font-size: 18px;
       font-weight: bold;
      }
     </style>
    </head>
    <body id="body">
     <form id="sign-up" action="success.php" method="post">
      <div id="row-one">
       <input type="text" id="first-name" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" maxlength="15">
      </div>
      <div id="span-container">
       <span id="first-name-warning-message" class="text-danger"> </span>
      </div>
      <div id="row-two">
       <input type="text" id="last-name" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" maxlength="15">
      </div>
      <div id="span-container">
       <span id="last-name-warning-message" class="text-danger"> </span>
      </div>
      <div id="row-three">
       <input class="date-picker" id="date-of-birth" name="user_dob" placeholder="Date Of Birth" readonly="true">
      </div>
      <div id="span-container">
       <span id="dob-warning-message" class="text-danger"> </span>
      </div>
      <div id="row-four">
       <button id="sign-up-button" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"> Sign Up </button>
      </div>
     </form>
     <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#first-name-warning-message').hide();
       $('#last-name-warning-message').hide();
       $('#dob-warning-message').hide();

       var first_name_error=false;
       var last_name_error=false;
       var dob_error=false;

       $('#first-name').focusout(function(){
        validate_first_name();
       });

       $('#last-name').focusout(function(){
        validate_last_name();
       });

       $('#date-of-birth').focusout(function(){
        validate_date_of_birth();
       });

       function validate_first_name(){
        var first_name=$('#first-name').val();
        var first_name_regex=/^[a-zA-Z ]{3,15}$/;
        if(first_name.length==''){
         $('#first-name-warning-message').show();
         $('#first-name-warning-message').html("Please Enter Your First Name !");
         first_name_error=true;
        }
        else if(first_name.length<3){
         $('#first-name-warning-message').show();
         $('#first-name-warning-message').html("First Name Not Valid !");
         first_name_error=true;
        }
        else if(!first_name_regex.test(first_name)){
         $('#first-name-warning-message').show();
         $('#first-name-warning-message').html("First Name Must Not Contain Any Digits Or Symbols !");
         first_name_error=true;
        }
        else{
         $('#first-name-warning-message').hide();
        }
       }

       function validate_last_name(){
        var last_name=$('#last-name').val();
        var last_name_regex=/^[a-zA-Z ]{3,15}$/;

        if(last_name.length==''){
         $('#last-name-warning-message').show();
         $('#last-name-warning-message').html("Please Enter Your Last Name !");
         last_name_error=true;
        }
        else if(last_name.length<3){
         $('#last-name-warning-message').show();
         $('#last-name-warning-message').html("Last Name Not Valid !");
         last_name_error=true;
        }
        else if(!last_name_regex.test(last_name)){
         $('#last-name-warning-message').show();
         $('#last-name-warning-message').html("Last Name Must Not Contain Any Digits Or Symbols !");
         last_name_error=true;
        }
        else{
         $('#last-name-warning-message').hide();
        }
       }
                function validate_date_of_birth(){
                    if($("#date-of-birth").datepicker("getDate") === null) {
                     $('#dob-warning-message').html("Please Enter Your Date Of Birth !");
                        $('#dob-warning-message').show();
                        dob_error=true;
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#dob-warning-message').hide();
                    }
                    return false;
                }
       $("#date-of-birth").datepicker({
                    dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true
                }); 

          $('#sign-up').submit(function(){
           first_name_error=false;
           last_name_error=false;
           dob_error=false;

           validate_first_name();
           validate_last_name();
           validate_date_of_birth();

           if((first_name_error==false)&&(last_name_error==false)&&(dob_error==false)){
            return true;
           }
           else{
            return false;
           }
          });
      });
     </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```